# WindowBuilder Eclipse GWT_HOME missing

Tags: eclipse, windowbuilder

I installed Google WindowBuilder plugin in Eclipse successfully (in the sense that it went smoothly and reported no errors).

I have an existing working Java project called `host` that runs fine.

But when I try to convert `host` by selecting *Convert project to a GWT project...* it reports an error on build:

> Unbound classpath variable: 'GWT_HOME/gwt-user.jar' in project 'host'

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283272/gwt-home-variable-setup-problems):

Which tells me that I have to set `GWT_HOME` to the WindowBuilder installation directory.

But I cannot find that directory.  More specifically, I have done a recursive directory-tree search of my entire user space:

```
$ find . -name gwt-user.jar -print

$
```

Which seems to imply that, despite the apparently successful installation of the WindowBuilder plugin, at least one file is missing.

I am running Eclipse SDK Version: 3.5.2, with Java version 1.6.0_22
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.6) (6b22-1.10.6-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode, sharing) and I installed WindowBuilder from [here](http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.5):

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283272/gwt-home-variable-setup-problems) and yes , that describes the way to get GWT installation path.It's in 
:

```
/opt/eclipse/plugins/
```

You have to CD to /opt/eclipse/plugins/ and you will find it there , e.g. in my case it's :

```
/opt/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201206290132-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/doc/javadoc/com/google/gwt
```

If you cannot locate it there , just look at the installation path in Eclipse main menu:

```
Preferences >> Google >> Web Toolkit
```

this answer is the same as @fachexot , nothing new .

Comment: Sorry - should have mentioned: on my system that directory is /usr/lib/eclipse/plugins.  It's not there either...

Comment: Sorry - should have mentioned: for me that directory is /usr/lib/eclipse/plugins.  It's not there either...  "Google" isn't in my Preferences, but "WindowBuilder" is.  But there is no tab under it called "Web Toolkit". There is a lot of google.gwt.eclipse stuff in my ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.5.0_155965261/plugins directory, where I expected it to be, but not quite all of it...  If there was a way to remove (rather than disable) a plugin from Eclipse I would do that and start again. But this: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in%3F tells me that that way misery lies...